# d3.js area graph has a final line on the wrong side

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm attempting to get my area chart to work using two arrays for the x and y-axes, with both scaled. My issue is that the final few lines of the path don't complete along the right and bottom sides of the graph, but rather go directly from the last y-value back to the origin.

Here is the code, a screenshot is attached below as well.

```js
var dataArray = [243.1,246.3,250.1,260.3,266.2,272.9,279.5,280.7,275.4,271.7,273.3,271.0,281.2,
    290.7,308.5,320.3,336.4,344.5,351.8,356.6,360.2,361.4,368.1,381.2,388.5,392.3,
    391.7,386.5,385.9,386.7,391.6,400.3,413.8,422.2,430.9,437.8,440.5,446.8,452.0,
    461.3,470.6,472.8,480.3,475.7,468.4,472.8,486.7,500.4,511.1,524.2,525.2,529.3,
    543.3,542.7,546.0,541.1,545.9,557.4,568.2,581.6,595.2,602.6,609.6,613.1,622.7,
    631.8,645.0,654.8,671.1,680.8,692.8,698.4,719.2,732.4,750.2,773.1,797.3,807.2,
    820.8,834.9,846.0,851.1,866.6,883.2,911.1,936.3,952.3,970.1,995.4,1011.4,1032.0,
    1040.7,1053.5,1070.1,1088.5,1091.5,1137.8,1159.4,1180.3,1193.6,1233.8,1270.1,
    1293.8,1332.0,1380.7,1417.6,1436.8,1479.1,1494.7,1534.2,1563.4,1603.0,1619.6,
    1656.4,1713.8,1765.9,1824.5,1856.9,1890.5,1938.4,1992.5,2060.2,2122.4,2168.7,
    2208.7,2336.6,2398.9,2482.2,2531.6,2595.9,2670.4,2730.7,2796.5,2799.9,2860.0,
    2993.5,3131.8,3167.3,3261.2,3283.5,3273.8,3331.3,3367.1,3407.8,3480.3,3583.8,
    3692.3,3796.1,3912.8,4015.0,4087.4,4147.6,4237.0,4302.3,4394.6,4453.1,4516.3,
    4555.2,4619.6,4669.4,4736.2,4821.5,4900.5,5022.7,5090.6,5207.7,5299.5,5412.7,
    5527.4,5628.4,5711.6,5763.4,5890.8,5974.7,6029.5,6023.3,6054.9,6143.6,6218.4,
    6279.3,6380.8,6492.3,6586.5,6697.6,6748.2,6829.6,6904.2,7032.8,7136.3,7269.8,
    7352.3,7476.7,7545.3,7604.9,7706.5,7799.5,7893.1,8061.5,8159.0,8287.1,8402.1,
    8551.9,8691.8,8788.3,8889.7,8994.7,9146.5,9325.7,9447.1,9557.0,9712.3,9926.1,
    10031.0,10278.3,10357.4,10472.3,10508.1,10638.4,10639.5,10701.3,10834.4,10934.8,
    11037.1,11103.8,11230.1,11370.7,11625.1,11816.8,11988.4,12181.4,12367.7,12562.2,
    12813.7,12974.1,13205.4,13381.6,13648.9,13799.8,13908.5,14066.4,14233.2,14422.3,
    14569.7,14685.3,14668.4,14813.0,14843.0,14549.9,14383.9,14340.4,14384.1,14566.5,
    14681.1,14888.6,15057.7,15230.2,15238.4,15460.9,15587.1,15785.3,15973.9,16121.9,
    16227.9,16297.3,16475.4,16541.4,16749.3,16999.9,17025.2,17285.6,17569.4,17692.2,
    17783.6,17998.3,18141.9,18222.8,18281.6,18450.1,18675.3,18869.4,19007.3];

var dataYears = [1947.25,1947.5,1947.75,1948,1948.25,1948.5,1948.75,1949,1949.25,1949.5,1949.75,
    1950,1950.25,1950.5,1950.75,1951,1951.25,1951.5,1951.75,1952,1952.25,1952.5,
    1952.75,1953,1953.25,1953.5,1953.75,1954,1954.25,1954.5,1954.75,1955,1955.25,
    1955.5,1955.75,1956,1956.25,1956.5,1956.75,1957,1957.25,1957.5,1957.75,1958,
    1958.25,1958.5,1958.75,1959,1959.25,1959.5,1959.75,1960,1960.25,1960.5,1960.75,
    1961,1961.25,1961.5,1961.75,1962,1962.25,1962.5,1962.75,1963,1963.25,1963.5,
    1963.75,1964,1964.25,1964.5,1964.75,1965,1965.25,1965.5,1965.75,1966,1966.25,
    1966.5,1966.75,1967,1967.25,1967.5,1967.75,1968,1968.25,1968.5,1968.75,1969,
    1969.25,1969.5,1969.75,1970,1970.25,1970.5,1970.75,1971,1971.25,1971.5,1971.75,
    1972,1972.25,1972.5,1972.75,1973,1973.25,1973.5,1973.75,1974,1974.25,1974.5,
    1974.75,1975,1975.25,1975.5,1975.75,1976,1976.25,1976.5,1976.75,1977,1977.25,
    1977.5,1977.75,1978,1978.25,1978.5,1978.75,1979,1979.25,1979.5,1979.75,1980,
    1980.25,1980.5,1980.75,1981,1981.25,1981.5,1981.75,1982,1982.25,1982.5,1982.75,
    1983,1983.25,1983.5,1983.75,1984,1984.25,1984.5,1984.75,1985,1985.25,1985.5,
    1985.75,1986,1986.25,1986.5,1986.75,1987,1987.25,1987.5,1987.75,1988,1988.25,
    1988.5,1988.75,1989,1989.25,1989.5,1989.75,1990,1990.25,1990.5,1990.75,1991,
    1991.25,1991.5,1991.75,1992,1992.25,1992.5,1992.75,1993,1993.25,1993.5,1993.75,
    1994,1994.25,1994.5,1994.75,1995,1995.25,1995.5,1995.75,1996,1996.25,1996.5,
    1996.75,1997,1997.25,1997.5,1997.75,1998,1998.25,1998.5,1998.75,1999,1999.25,
    1999.5,1999.75,2000,2000.25,2000.5,2000.75,2001,2001.25,2001.5,2001.75,2002,
    2002.25,2002.5,2002.75,2003,2003.25,2003.5,2003.75,2004,2004.25,2004.5,2004.75,
    2005,2005.25,2005.5,2005.75,2006,2006.25,2006.5,2006.75,2007,2007.25,2007.5,
    2007.75,2008,2008.25,2008.5,2008.75,2009,2009.25,2009.5,2009.75,2010,2010.25,
    2010.5,2010.75,2011,2011.25,2011.5,2011.75,2012,2012.25,2012.5,2012.75,2013,
    2013.25,2013.5,2013.75,2014,2014.25,2014.5,2014.75,2015,2015.25,2015.5,2015.75,
    2016,2016.25,2016.5,2016.75,2017];

var height = 600;
var width = 800;

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0,d3.max(dataArray)])
 .range([height, 0]);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain(d3.extent(dataYears))
 .range([0,width]);

var margin = {left:100,right:50,top:40,bottom:0}

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(4).tickPadding(10).tickSize(10);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

var area = d3.area()
    .x(function(d,i){return x(dataYears[i]);})
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d){return y(d);});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height",height).attr("width",width)
var chartGroup = svg.append("g").attr("class","graph").attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");

chartGroup.append("path").attr("d",area(dataArray));
chartGroup.append("g").attr("class","axis y").call(yAxis);
chartGroup.append("g").attr("class","axis x").attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")").call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: It is easiest to help if we can see what you are doing, if you include a snippet of your code showing your problem, we will be better able to help.

Comment: @AndrewReid, I've inserted the JS file above. I was able to fix the issue by adding an additional value to the 'dataYears' array, but I would hope that adding a fake data point is not the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the code down, there is just an issue with your data arrays.
The years array is lacking one value (length 280) compared with the data array (length 281). If these are the same length,  you'll get the desired result. I've added a new year value to the year array (2017.25), and it displays as intended. See snippet below:

```js
var dataArray = [243.1,246.3,250.1,260.3,266.2,272.9,279.5,280.7,275.4,271.7,273.3,271.0,281.2,
    290.7,308.5,320.3,336.4,344.5,351.8,356.6,360.2,361.4,368.1,381.2,388.5,392.3,
    391.7,386.5,385.9,386.7,391.6,400.3,413.8,422.2,430.9,437.8,440.5,446.8,452.0,
    461.3,470.6,472.8,480.3,475.7,468.4,472.8,486.7,500.4,511.1,524.2,525.2,529.3,
    543.3,542.7,546.0,541.1,545.9,557.4,568.2,581.6,595.2,602.6,609.6,613.1,622.7,
    631.8,645.0,654.8,671.1,680.8,692.8,698.4,719.2,732.4,750.2,773.1,797.3,807.2,
    820.8,834.9,846.0,851.1,866.6,883.2,911.1,936.3,952.3,970.1,995.4,1011.4,1032.0,
    1040.7,1053.5,1070.1,1088.5,1091.5,1137.8,1159.4,1180.3,1193.6,1233.8,1270.1,
    1293.8,1332.0,1380.7,1417.6,1436.8,1479.1,1494.7,1534.2,1563.4,1603.0,1619.6,
    1656.4,1713.8,1765.9,1824.5,1856.9,1890.5,1938.4,1992.5,2060.2,2122.4,2168.7,
    2208.7,2336.6,2398.9,2482.2,2531.6,2595.9,2670.4,2730.7,2796.5,2799.9,2860.0,
    2993.5,3131.8,3167.3,3261.2,3283.5,3273.8,3331.3,3367.1,3407.8,3480.3,3583.8,
    3692.3,3796.1,3912.8,4015.0,4087.4,4147.6,4237.0,4302.3,4394.6,4453.1,4516.3,
    4555.2,4619.6,4669.4,4736.2,4821.5,4900.5,5022.7,5090.6,5207.7,5299.5,5412.7,
    5527.4,5628.4,5711.6,5763.4,5890.8,5974.7,6029.5,6023.3,6054.9,6143.6,6218.4,
    6279.3,6380.8,6492.3,6586.5,6697.6,6748.2,6829.6,6904.2,7032.8,7136.3,7269.8,
    7352.3,7476.7,7545.3,7604.9,7706.5,7799.5,7893.1,8061.5,8159.0,8287.1,8402.1,
    8551.9,8691.8,8788.3,8889.7,8994.7,9146.5,9325.7,9447.1,9557.0,9712.3,9926.1,
    10031.0,10278.3,10357.4,10472.3,10508.1,10638.4,10639.5,10701.3,10834.4,10934.8,
    11037.1,11103.8,11230.1,11370.7,11625.1,11816.8,11988.4,12181.4,12367.7,12562.2,
    12813.7,12974.1,13205.4,13381.6,13648.9,13799.8,13908.5,14066.4,14233.2,14422.3,
    14569.7,14685.3,14668.4,14813.0,14843.0,14549.9,14383.9,14340.4,14384.1,14566.5,
    14681.1,14888.6,15057.7,15230.2,15238.4,15460.9,15587.1,15785.3,15973.9,16121.9,
    16227.9,16297.3,16475.4,16541.4,16749.3,16999.9,17025.2,17285.6,17569.4,17692.2,
    17783.6,17998.3,18141.9,18222.8,18281.6,18450.1,18675.3,18869.4,19007.3];

var dataYears = [1947.25,1947.5,1947.75,1948,1948.25,1948.5,1948.75,1949,1949.25,1949.5,1949.75,
    1950,1950.25,1950.5,1950.75,1951,1951.25,1951.5,1951.75,1952,1952.25,1952.5,
    1952.75,1953,1953.25,1953.5,1953.75,1954,1954.25,1954.5,1954.75,1955,1955.25,
    1955.5,1955.75,1956,1956.25,1956.5,1956.75,1957,1957.25,1957.5,1957.75,1958,
    1958.25,1958.5,1958.75,1959,1959.25,1959.5,1959.75,1960,1960.25,1960.5,1960.75,
    1961,1961.25,1961.5,1961.75,1962,1962.25,1962.5,1962.75,1963,1963.25,1963.5,
    1963.75,1964,1964.25,1964.5,1964.75,1965,1965.25,1965.5,1965.75,1966,1966.25,
    1966.5,1966.75,1967,1967.25,1967.5,1967.75,1968,1968.25,1968.5,1968.75,1969,
    1969.25,1969.5,1969.75,1970,1970.25,1970.5,1970.75,1971,1971.25,1971.5,1971.75,
    1972,1972.25,1972.5,1972.75,1973,1973.25,1973.5,1973.75,1974,1974.25,1974.5,
    1974.75,1975,1975.25,1975.5,1975.75,1976,1976.25,1976.5,1976.75,1977,1977.25,
    1977.5,1977.75,1978,1978.25,1978.5,1978.75,1979,1979.25,1979.5,1979.75,1980,
    1980.25,1980.5,1980.75,1981,1981.25,1981.5,1981.75,1982,1982.25,1982.5,1982.75,
    1983,1983.25,1983.5,1983.75,1984,1984.25,1984.5,1984.75,1985,1985.25,1985.5,
    1985.75,1986,1986.25,1986.5,1986.75,1987,1987.25,1987.5,1987.75,1988,1988.25,
    1988.5,1988.75,1989,1989.25,1989.5,1989.75,1990,1990.25,1990.5,1990.75,1991,
    1991.25,1991.5,1991.75,1992,1992.25,1992.5,1992.75,1993,1993.25,1993.5,1993.75,
    1994,1994.25,1994.5,1994.75,1995,1995.25,1995.5,1995.75,1996,1996.25,1996.5,
    1996.75,1997,1997.25,1997.5,1997.75,1998,1998.25,1998.5,1998.75,1999,1999.25,
    1999.5,1999.75,2000,2000.25,2000.5,2000.75,2001,2001.25,2001.5,2001.75,2002,
    2002.25,2002.5,2002.75,2003,2003.25,2003.5,2003.75,2004,2004.25,2004.5,2004.75,
    2005,2005.25,2005.5,2005.75,2006,2006.25,2006.5,2006.75,2007,2007.25,2007.5,
    2007.75,2008,2008.25,2008.5,2008.75,2009,2009.25,2009.5,2009.75,2010,2010.25,
    2010.5,2010.75,2011,2011.25,2011.5,2011.75,2012,2012.25,2012.5,2012.75,2013,
    2013.25,2013.5,2013.75,2014,2014.25,2014.5,2014.75,2015,2015.25,2015.5,2015.75,
    2016,2016.25,2016.5,2016.75,2017,2017.25];

var height = 600;
var width = 800;
var margin = {left:100,right:50,top:40,bottom:0}

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0,d3.max(dataArray)])
 .range([height, 0]);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain(d3.extent(dataYears))
 .range([0,width]);



var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(4).tickPadding(10).tickSize(10);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

var area = d3.area()
    .x(function(d,i){return x(dataYears[i]);})
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d){return y(d);});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height",height+margin.top+margin.bottom).attr("width",width+margin.right+margin.left)
var chartGroup = svg.append("g").attr("class","graph").attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");

chartGroup.append("path").attr("d",area(dataArray));
chartGroup.append("g").attr("class","axis y").call(yAxis);
chartGroup.append("g").attr("class","axis x").attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Alright, I guess I was just missing a value. Thanks for helping out.